# Client player not visible in server unity 5

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, unity-networking

Here I am trying to instantiate Player in client with button click. Here is my script. I can see server in client but can not see client player in server. Anyone can help.?

I am Instantiate player with custom script. Player instantiate after button click.

By pressing btnPlayer button Player instantiate.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Network_Manager_Custom : NetworkManager {

    private Animator anim;
    //[SerializeField]private GameObject btnDisconnect;
    [SerializeField]private GameObject _player, SpawnPointsParent, btnPlayer;
    [SerializeField]private List<GameObject> sPoints;
    private bool checkState = false;
    private int iPos = 0;

    GameObject ga;

    public void StartupHost()
    {       
        setPort ();
        NetworkManager.singleton.StartHost ();
        sPoints = new List<GameObject> ();
    }

    public void JoinGame()
    {
        setIPAddress ();
        setPort (); 
        NetworkManager.singleton.StartClient ();
        iPos = iPos + 1;
    }

    public void setIPAddress()
    {
        string IPAddress = GameObject.Find ("InputFieldIPAddress").transform.FindChild("Text").GetComponent<Text>().text;
        NetworkManager.singleton.networkAddress = IPAddress;
        Debug.Log ("IPAddress : "+ IPAddress);
    }
    void setPort()
    {
        NetworkManager.singleton.networkPort = 7777;
    }

    void OnLevelWasLoaded(int level)
    {
        if (level == 0) {
            SetupMenuScreenButtons ();
        } else {            
            SetupOtherSceneButtons ();
        }
    }
    void SetupMenuScreenButtons()
    {
        GameObject.Find ("btnStartHost").GetComponent<Button>().onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        GameObject.Find ("btnStartHost").GetComponent<Button> ().onClick.AddListener (StartupHost);

        GameObject.Find ("btnJoinGame").GetComponent<Button>().onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        GameObject.Find ("btnJoinGame").GetComponent<Button> ().onClick.AddListener (JoinGame);

    }
    void SetupOtherSceneButtons()
    {       
        //btnDisconnect = GameObject.Find ("btnDisconnect");
        //if (btnDisconnect != null) {
        GetListOfPlayer ();

        GameObject.Find ("btnDisconnect").GetComponent<Button> ().onClick.RemoveAllListeners ();
        GameObject.Find ("btnDisconnect").GetComponent<Button> ().onClick.AddListener (NetworkManager.singleton.StopHost);

        GameObject.Find ("btnPlayer").GetComponent<Button>().onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        GameObject.Find ("btnPlayer").GetComponent<Button> ().onClick.AddListener (PlayerInstantiateHere);

        //} else {
        //  Debug.Log("btnDisconnect not available.!");
        //}
    }
    void GetListOfPlayer()
    {
        if(SpawnPointsParent == null)
            SpawnPointsParent = GameObject.Find ("SpawnPoints");

        foreach(Transform t in SpawnPointsParent.transform)
        {
            sPoints.Add (t.gameObject);
        }
    }

    public void PlayerInstantiateHere()
    {       
        if (_player != null) {
            //NetworkManager.Instantiate (_player, sPoints [iPos].transform.position, sPoints [iPos].transform.rotation);
            GameObject ga = (GameObject) NetworkBehaviour.Instantiate(_player, sPoints [iPos].transform.position, sPoints [iPos].transform.rotation);
            ClientScene.RegisterPrefab (ga);
            NetworkServer.Spawn (ga);

        }
        Debug.Log ("Player button clicked.!");
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you define it a bit more " I can see server in client but can not see client player in server. Anyone can help.?"

Comment: I can see server player in client but can not see client player in server. so, in server only one player and client side two player. client player not showing in server/Host

Comment: what about each player camera and where each player is spawning? position?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems ok, I guess you both player are spawning at the same position. Make it radomize by provide different position for this reason: 
Please add some empty gameobject (position) and add [NetworkStartPosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkStartPosition.html) Component. Finally also set [PlayerSpawnMethod](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.PlayerSpawnMethod.html) to round robin.

Comment: No If client player instantiate then it should display in host (my pc unity editor). but I can see only host player. There are no client player display in hierarchy.

Comment: can you upload your minimum project somewhere, so i can check.

Comment: i have run your code, it is perfectly working. just make sure that your events are properly attached with buttons. I assigned manually (didn't use OnLevelWasLoaded event). further instead of using your custom code for random position use NetworkstartPosition as answer suggested.